# ESP8266 - Sending a software Reset Command

Tags: esp8266, reset

I have an ESP8266 running an Arduino code to control a dual relay device ( Up, Down, Off ), both from a physical switch and MQTT commands. After mounting the device in place I have no access in case of a need to reset ( just as a precaution ).

My workaround:

1) condition: function that on 4 detection of 4 repeated UP button presses - it should send a reboot signal.

2) the reboot signal is :

```
void sendReset() {
  Serial.println("Sending Reset command");
  Serial.println(1/0);
}
```

`sendReset` function actually reboots the device and boot occurs as needed, BUT - is doing it this way is a valid solution ? does boot process actually boots all services and freeing/ memory or any other.... AS NEEDED ?

Guy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1/0 is an exception (divide by zero). esp8266 arduino core has soft reset: `ESP.reset()`. Calling this function you get a valid reset.

Note to software reset. esp8266 has a bug. If software reset (or exception) is executed in program started right after the flashing, the board goes back to flashing mode because the flashing flag is still active. Perhaps you noticed that after flashing the bootloader doesn't reset the board, but executes the flashed code.

Comment: Hi! Yes I know it is an exception, but it causes a reset. Does an Arduino board has also a reset function?

Comment: read the answer, please

Comment: I read your answer before it was edited ( 1st paragraph only ). Thanks for additional information. My question in the comment was a generelized question regarding Arduino boards ( Nano for example ) it it has also a `reset` command.

Comment: Nano? you write the code for esp8266. yes there is a reset solution for AVR too. with watchdog

Comment: Yes ! my code is for esp8266 and the reset command is intended for this code, but I wanted to know if such command exists for Arduino boards. thank you

Comment: not one general. different Arduino cores have different solutions for reset. SAMD has NVIC_SystemReset()

Comment: In case of serial upload, you need to power off and back on the port, in order to execute again `sendReset` to work as needed. What is the workaround in causes of OTA, that powering off is not an option ?

Comment: OTA makes ESP.reset(). it is good. (it doesn't work only at first reset after serial upload)